# Creating a trigger in a CellTemplate for a ListView? (confusion with Templates in general)

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I'm starting to get a little confused as I delve further into WPF and I feel like this example will help in better understanding things. My requirement is this: I have a ListView that is using a binding to a collection of plain .NET objects, I want to do two things:

1) highlight the cell of a row in the ListView if the value is a certain value - I figure I can use the GridViewColumn.CellTemplate for this and create a DataTemplate with a DataTrigger, however I am becoming confused here - is the DataType for the DataTemplate supposed to be the ListViewItem or is it supposed to be the type of the underlying object itself?

This is a general point of confusion for me in WPF ..not knowing when to type it to the underlying collection object (which I've seen in examples) vs the list-item type itself. Here is my first attempt:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Position">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=PositionCode}"></TextBlock>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PositionCode}" Value="QB">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PositionCode}" Value="RB">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PositionCode}" Value="WR">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

However, this not surprisingly leads to the error message

```
Cannot find the Template Property 'Background' on the type 'System.Windows.Controls.ContentPresenter'
```

2) similar to 1) I want to have a similar rule on another criteria I want to highlight the entire row, instead of just the cell based on a similar DataTrigger property but same time I want the cell highlighting to take precedence over the row highlighting.

How would I do this and what template do I need to override to do this? I'm guessing it's the ListView.ItemTemplate but what would the data type be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
<GridViewColumn Header="Position">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <TextBlock Name="TextBlockName" Text="{Binding Path=PositionCode}"></TextBlock>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PositionCode}" Value="QB">
                    <Setter TargetName="TextBlockName" Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PositionCode}" Value="RB">
                    <Setter TargetName="TextBlockName" Property="Foreground" Value="Green" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PositionCode}" Value="WR">
                    <Setter TargetName="TextBlockName" Property="Foreground" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Comment: Aye that works, thank ye kindly. I also solved it using a value converter on the properties I want to conditionally bind on

Answer (score 2):

I think dvvrd's answer addresses your first question.  For the other part (building the row style), you can use the *ItemContainerStyleSelector*.

```
<ListView ItemContainerStyleSelector="{StaticResource Selector}" ...
```

I wrote a simple implementation like this:

```
public class RowStyleSelector : StyleSelector
{
    public override System.Windows.Style SelectStyle(object item, System.Windows.DependencyObject container)
    {
        var i = (item as Item);
        if (i.I == 0) return (Style)App.Current.Resources["Selected"];
        else return (Style)App.Current.Resources["Normal"];
    }
}
```

Then the different styles, along with the selector reference, go in App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <res:RowStyleSelector x:Key="Selector" />
    <Style x:Key="Selected" TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkGray" />
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="Normal" TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue" />
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

This approach effectively sets the background color depending on criteria in your model (the *Item* class in my example), with the column highlighting still in effect.

Comment: That works too - thanks! 

I think for me the broader issue in terms of understanding is the fact that each item in a bound list is wrapped by a content control (eg ListBoxItem, ComboBoxItem etc.) and whatever template you specify for the ItemTemplate property of the list, gets used as the ContentTemplate (not ControlTemplate - this always confuses me since the words look the same) of each item in the list itself